# Jpa batch выгрузка и сохранение большого количества записей в одном потоке

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

Есть задача предохранять данные из одной таблицы psg в другую.
есть реализация на JDBC template c batch.
мне интересно есть ли реализации на Jpa Batch чтобы частями вычитывать данные и сразу сохранять в одном потоке.

т.е. сейчас у меня сделано вычитывание и сохранение в цикле

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeCycle; i++) {
            int page = i * 100;
            int size = i * 100 + 100 - 1;

            Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, size);
            List<AccType> accTypeList = accTypeRepository.findAll(pageable).getContent();
            accTypeRBCRepository.saveAll(accTypeList);
}
```

код отрабатывает, но меня смущает, что выглядит как-то коряво с

```
int page = i * 100;
int size = i * 100 + 100 - 1;
```

нет какого-то оптимизированного способа, чтобы запустить поток и в нем партиционно согласно batch_size данные вычитывались и сохранялись. т.е. например в таблице из которой читаю 1 млн записей. batch_size == 100 и так кусочками данные бы вычитывалиь и сохранялись в одном потоке.

настройки:

```
jpa:
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        order_inserts: true
        order_updates: true
        batch_versioned_data: true
        generate_statistics: true
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 100
        naming-strategy: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
```

Comment: Все настройки находятся в разделе spring? Полный путь должен быть таким -`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size`

Comment: да в spring: ...

Comment: Попробуйте прочитать про Spring Batch (https://www.baeldung.com/introduction-to-spring-batch) в нем есть постраничный риадер из БД и параллельная обработка в несколько потоков